# this.get('session') returns undefined for torii

Tags: ember.js, torii

I'm trying to use Facebook login using torii in an Ember app.
I am using ember 2.0 (2.11 to be specific).
Below is handlebar of my component my-login

```
{{#paper-button raised=true onClick=(action "loginUsingFacebook")}}Login Using Faceboo{{/paper-button}}
```

action in my component is defined as

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    actions:{
        loginUsingFacebook(){
            let session = this.get('session'); //session comes undefined
            console.log(session);
        }
    }
});
```

i have setup my environment as defined `[here][1]`

in my application route i am using it as

```
{{#my-login}} {{/my-login}}
{{outlet}}
```

I am using torii-adapter which on path app/torii-adapters and exactly as provided [here](https://github.com/vestorly/torii)

i have installed torii using npm install torii. Could you please let me know what i am missing.

I am not able to get the session.

Comment: Are you sure about the **this.get('session');** call? As far as I see, the code calls it on **loginUsingFacebook**, not on your ember **Component**.

Comment: loginUsingFacebook is defined inside my component only.

Comment: "I am not able to get the session." &ndash; What is the concrete behavior and the console output? Any error thrown?

Comment: No i'm not getting any error. I guess session is only available in route but when i define the action in route, i get error "Assertion Failed: An action named 'loginUsingFacebook' was not found in (generated application controller)"

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to inject the `session` into the component before trying to get access of it?

```
session: Ember.inject.service('session')
```

Comment: i added this in my component, but still it doesn't make difference